# How to break out of a while loop in Python 3.3

Tags: python

```
m = int(input("First number (0 to stop): "))
n = int(input("Second number: "))

def gcd(a, b):
   while b != 0:
        c = a % b
        a = b
        b = c
        if b == 0:
            break
   return a

print ("The greatest common divisor of", n,"and", m, "is", abs(gcd(m,n)))
```

How do I break out of this while loop, when m is equal to 0.

Comment: What `while` loop? The only `while` there is inside `gcd`, and it doesn't use `m`. Is there an outer `while` you're not showing us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want an outer loop, judging from your input hint of `(0 to stop)`:

```
def gcd(a, b):
   while b != 0:
        c = a % b
        a, b = b, c  # tuple assignment FTW!
        if b == 0:
            break
   return a

while True:
    m = int(input("First number (0 to stop): "))
    if m == 0:
        break
    n = int(input("Second number: "))
    print("The greatest common divisor of {0} and {1} is {2}".format(n, m, abs(gcd(m, n))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. An outer loop did fix the problem I was having.