# How can you go out of a function in python?

Tags: python, function

How can you go out of a function in python??

Look at this program

For example:

```py
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

level = 0
x = 0

def eg_func():
    global x
    x = 10

def eg_func2():
    global x
    x = 2

while True:
    if level == 0:       
        eg_func()

    if playing == True:
        eg_func2()   

    print(x)

pygame.quit()
quit
```

So, how can I do that `eg_func()` stops but level keeps being `0` and not changing global -> because in my program I can't change it?

Thanks for everything, probably it's a simple thing.

Comment: Check [Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

Comment: Do any of these answer your question? [Cannot break out of while loop in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318622/cannot-break-out-of-while-loop-in-python) | [Can't break out of Python loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922925/cant-break-out-of-python-loop) | [How to break out of while loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594522/how-to-break-out-of-while-loop-in-python)

Comment: Or these? [I am unable to break out of python (while) loop, and unsure why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75537809/i-am-unable-to-break-out-of-python-while-loop-and-unsure-why) | [breaking out of python loop without using break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773965/breaking-out-of-python-loop-without-using-break) | [How to break out of a while loop in Python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995405/how-to-break-out-of-a-while-loop-in-python-3-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emm, using `return`

```
level = 0
x = 0

def eg_func():
    global x
    x = 10
    return x

def eg_func2():
    global x
    x = 2
    return x

while True:

    if level == 0:       
        eg_func()

    if playing == True:
        eg_func2()   

    print(x)
```

But Im not sure that you actualy need the global

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `global x` to tell Python to change the value of the global `x` value, instead of defining a local `x` variable inside the function.

```py
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

level = 0
x = 0

def eg_func():
    global x
    x = 10

def eg_func2():
    x = 2

while True:
    if level == 0:       
        eg_func()

    if playing == True:
        eg_func2()   

    print(x)

pygame.quit()
quit
```